# How to get data from tables linked to a single user

Tags: php, mysql, html

First of all thank you for help me in advance.

I am looking to make a system were i am using 1 mysql DB and 2 tables or more and connect the tables to a user in a session. So lets suppose that the user logs in in a location, after login he can view from another table the data relative to this user, like a support ticket system (very simple one).

So i created a login system with sessions and then i want to display from another table only the data from that single user but when i do this i get all the data from the table, other users can see other users submissions and i wanna stop that and make it single user, single data display from that user only.

So here is the codes i am using:

```
<?php  
 // Validate Client Details  
 session_start();  
 if(!isset($_SESSION["user_username"]))  
 {  
      header("location:index.php?action=login");  
 }  
?>
```

Then i got this code to display the records:

```
    <?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "helpdesk");  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN tickets ON users.user_id = tickets.ticket_id";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); 
 ?>
```

It works great but displays all and not just the single user details.

The Output i am using:

```
<table class="table table-striped">  
                      <tr>  
                           <th>Ticket ID</th>
                           <th>Client Username</th>
                           <th>Ticket Issue</th>
                           <th>Message</th>
                           <th>Priority</th>  
                      </tr>  
                      <?php  
                      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                      {  
                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                           {  
                      ?>  
                      <tr>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["ticket_id"]; ?></td> 
                           <td><?php echo $row["user_username"];?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["ticket_issue"]; ?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $row["ticket_message"]; ?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $row["ticket_priority"]; ?></td>  
                      </tr>  
                      <?php  
                           }  
                      }  
                      ?>   
                 </table>
```

I hope someone can help me on this, my best regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed where condition

```
  $name=$_SESSION['user_username']

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN tickets ON users.user_id = tickets.ticket_id where user_username='$name'";
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130290/discussion-on-answer-by-shanu-k-k-how-to-get-data-from-tables-linked-to-a-single).